# Android R. Cant find tab in drawable folder (eve after cleaned and rebuild)

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-drawable

Just returend to a project I was working on the other day - when I left it, it was running, today **Error:(67, 93) error: cannot find symbol variable drawtab1**. Could it be something wrong with the manifest, tried to rebuild and clean. But drawtab1 is not showing..

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for login
        TabSpec Login = tabHost.newTabSpec("Login");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        Login.setIndicator("", getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawtab1));
        Intent LoginIntent = new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class);
        LoginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Login.setContent(LoginIntent);
```

This is **drawtab1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/login"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/login" />
</selector>
```

This is the **Mainfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tabdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"



            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab1Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab1" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab2" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab3Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab3" >
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: remove 1 in ur drawable name or delete old import=)

Comment: @PeDuCKA **WRONG**. Numbers in resource names are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a few cases here

```
 1. make sure there is not import android.R import statement.
 2. no error in typos in xml file.
 3. use only a-z and 0-9 for resource name it must not contain any capital letters or special symbol. Then clean and sync your project.
```